# How to instantiate prefab after destroying them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, destroy

I am doing a script that instantiate prefab in a list of prefab and then destroy them after a delay, but I want to re instantiate them if a enter into the trigger I tried something with a `bool` and a condition but that doesn't work.
There is the code :

```
public class CreateObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] Prefab;
    public Transform[] spawnPoint;

    private int i = 0;
    private int j = 0;
    private int k = 0;
    private float delay = 5f;
    private float delaySound ;
    public bool destroyOrNot;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // fonction on l'on fait apparaitre les objets de la liste selon son empty
        while (i<Prefab.Length && j < spawnPoint.Length  )  
        {
            GameObject clone =  Instantiate(Prefab[i] , spawnPoint[j].position, spawnPoint[j].rotation);

            Debug.Log("Detruire");

            destroyOrNOt = Destroy(clone ,delay);

            i++;
            j++;
            k++;

            if (destroyOrNot = true)
            {
                while (i < Prefab.Length && j < spawnPoint.Length )  
                {
                    GameObject clone =  Instantiate(Prefab[i] , spawnPoint[j].position, spawnPoint[j].rotation);

                    Debug.Log("Detruire");

                    destroyOrNot = Destroy(clone ,delay);
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    k++;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

That doesn't work and it tell me that we cant implicitly convert void to `bool` ! 
So please do you have any idea how can I do the thing ?
I am new in unity so maybe its something easy to do but I didn't figured how can I make it.
Thank you !

Comment: what's the purpose of `destroyOrNot = Destroy`? `Destroy` method doesn't return anything. maybe you wanted to write `destroyOrNot = true` instead?

Comment: i just want to write a condition that allow's me to know if prefab's are destroyed an then i cant just reinstantiate them but i dont know who to do it @Bizhan

Comment: as I said `Destroy` doesn't tell you whether or not the object was destroyed. It just destroys the object.

Comment: Also there is another gruesome error in your code: `if (destroyOrNot = true){` should be `if (destroyOrNot){`

Comment: Ok so how can i reinstatiate objects after destroy them if i enter in the trigger again ? @Bizhan

Comment: You can call `Instantiate` just like the first time you `Instantiate`d them. But that's **not** recommended. it looks like *neuromouse* already explained **object pooling** in the answer below

Comment: Is there any reason you are spawning multiple objects into the same positions? as thats whats happening with your current code, as for all i can tell you don't need the 2nd while loop

Answer (score 2):

First of all Destroy() method does not return any bool value so you have convertation mistake.

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you tried to do in this code snippet but I do not recommend you to "re-instantiate" deleted prefabs. Prefab instantiation (as wel as destruction) is very expensive operation and will cause perfomance issues.

If you use several **REUSABLE** objects you should using **OBJECT POOLING.**

The idea is simple. Basically you spawn all prefabs you need at start (when you loaded your level\started event\etc.) and disable all these spawned objects.

When you need one of them you just enable this object and reconfigure it (change positions, settings).  When you don't need object anymore - just disable it and take back to pool (some kind of list\collection).

And once you are COMPLETELY done with all these objects (dont need any of them anymore) - then Destroy all the pool.

This is the right way to deal with "reusable" objects.

You can learn more about object pooling here: [Object pooling in unity](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/object-pooling)

Comment: Just to add a note, changing the `isActive` or `isEnabled` properties of an object *can be* expensive also changing the `alpha` or `material` *is* expensive too. That's why there's a blind spot in many games where *some* the objects in the object pool (like bullets) are sitting there waiting to be repositioned into the camera. some other (those with heavy animation like particle effects or with heavy update loops like enemies) are just disabled wherever they were last time.